# tkinter.LabelFrame with Checkbutton labelwidget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

In `tkinter`, I'd like to have a frame similar to `LabelFrame`, but with a `Checkbutton` as the label.

After reading the [LabelFrame sources](https://github.com/tcltk/tk/blob/407b5e99e50da2fce5ac41043e29596a99d19862/generic/ttk/ttkFrame.c), I saw the `labelwidget` option and tried

```
checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(text=text)
checkbutton_frame = tk.LabelFrame(window, labelwidget=checkbutton)
```

It works visually, but the `Checkbutton` ends up being a child of `window` (`window.winfo_children()`). Alternatively:

```
checkbutton_frame = tk.LabelFrame(window)
checkbutton = tk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Hello, frame")
checkbutton_frame.configure(labelwidget=checkbutton)
```

makes the `Checkbutton` a child of the `LabelFrame`. The default, built-in `Label` of `LabelFrame` doesn't appear in `winfo_children`. Because I set `padx` and `pady` recursively after adding all my widgets, having the `Checkbutton` in `winfo_children` breaks the layout by moving the `Checkbutton` out of its anchored position. Is there a nice, clean way to substitute a `Checkbutton` for the `Label` in `LabelFrame` that maintains consistent (i.e. lack of any) descendant relationship? Answers with other workarounds are welcome.

**Minimal reproduction**

```
import tkinter as tk

def pack_configure_recursive(widget, **kwargs):
    stack = list(widget.winfo_children())
    while stack:
        descendent = stack.pop()
        try:
            stack.extend(descendent.winfo_children())
        except Exception:
            pass
        try:
            descendent.pack_configure(**kwargs)
        except Exception:
            pass


class CheckbuttonFrame(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        def pop_kwarg(name):
            nonlocal kwargs
            if name in kwargs:
                result = kwargs[name]
                del kwargs[name]
                return result
            else:
                return None

        text = pop_kwarg("text")
        self.variable = pop_kwarg("variable")
        self.command = pop_kwarg("command")

        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.configure(labelwidget=tk.Checkbutton(text=text, variable=self.variable, command=self.handler))  # Use this to make a child of the window
        # self.configure(labelwidget=tk.Checkbutton(self, text=text, variable=self.variable, command=self.handler))  # Use this to make a child of the frame

    def update_state(self):
        if self.variable:
            state = 'normal' if self.variable.get() else 'disable'
            stack = list(self.winfo_children())
            while stack:
                descendent = stack.pop()
                try:
                    stack.extend(descendent.winfo_children())
                except Exception:
                    pass
                try:
                    descendent.configure(state=state)
                except tk.TclError:
                    pass

    def handler(self):
        self.update_state()

        if self.command:
            external_command = self.command
            external_command()


window = tk.Tk()
option = tk.IntVar()
checkbutton_frame = CheckbuttonFrame(window, text="My option group", variable=option)
checkbutton_frame.pack()
tk.Label(checkbutton_frame, text="More widgets here").pack()
checkbutton_frame.update_state()
pack_configure_recursive(window, padx=2, pady=2)  # This line break the layout
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"The default, built-in Label of LabelFrame doesn't appear in winfo_children"_ - it never will, because the label of a labelframe isn't a widget.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You seem to want it to not be a child of `window`, and you don't want it to be a child of `checkbutton_frame`. It has to be the child of _something_, and being a child of the labelframe itself is the most logical solution.

Comment: "I'd like to have a frame similar to LabelFrame, but with a Checkbutton as the label." "Answers with other workarounds are welcome."

Comment: Yes, I know that's what you want. Either solution you proposed works, I don't understand why you need something different. The checkbutton must have a parent, what parent do you want it to have?

Comment: "I set padx and pady recursively after adding all my widgets, having the Checkbutton in winfo_children breaks the layout"

Comment: "breaks the layout" is unclear. How does it break the layout? Can't you just ignore it while you're iterating through all of the children?

Comment: It moves the checkbutton out of the anchored position, to the bottom of the frame (if a child of the frame) or under the frame (if a child of the window). The recursion is in the "pack_configure_recursive" function in the "More Code For Context" section.

Comment: That function isn't recursive, it's iterative.

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve] that illustrates what you mean by "breaks the layout".

Comment: Minimal reproduction is added

Comment: Btw, though the function does not call itself, an algorithm being applied to each node of a graph by iteratively traversing edges is still recursive. The recursion is not in the execution graph, but in the data graph. The location and contents of the stack is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The default, built-in Label of LabelFrame doesn't appear in winfo_children

That is because the built-in label of the `LabelFrame` isn't a widget.

> Is there a nice, clean way to substitute a Checkbutton for the Label in LabelFrame that maintains consistent (i.e. lack of any) descendant relationship? Answers with other workarounds are welcome.

No, there is not. The widget must be a descendant of something, there is simply no getting around that. And logically, it should probably be the descendant of the labelframe itself.

Any code you have to automatically re-pack widgets will need to skip over this widget.

Your code to call `pack_configure` should probably just ignore any widget not managed by pack, which you can do like this:

```
if descendent.winfo_manager() == "pack":
    descendent.pack_configure(**kwargs)
```

Comment: I suspected there might be an answer along these lines.